# How do I disable the enter key triggering an input in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, line-breaks

So I'm trying to make a simple word counting program, and I want it to be able to take enter keys as part of the essay it's reading without being triggered. (If anyone didn't understand, if I copy paste a paragraph that has the enter character in it, python will simply stop receiving the string at the enter char, because it thinks the user pressed enter, and it will take an incomplete input). I don't think I can explain this too well, so try copy pasting this into the code:

Line 1: `My name is Jack.`
Line 2: `Jack is my name.`

It only accepts line one.
Is there a workaround to this problem? Or is there a completely different approach I should take?

Code:

```
#Count words in an essay

import time

SA = input('Copy paste essay: \n')

word_list = SA.split(' ')
print (str(len(word_list)) + ' is the number of words in your essay')
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871100/python-3-how-to-ignore-line-breaks-when-using-input

Comment: @Codeman I don't quite understand why that happens; it works fine on my pc.

Comment: @DionSaputra Thank you for showing that up, I think I'll try those answers as well. However, is there a way to count the line breaks and run the input in a loop till all of them have been run through? Thanks

Comment: Like `SA.count('\n')`?

Comment: @AnnZen If you paste in a paragraph with multiple line breaks does it stop at the first one?

Comment: @AnnZen I wouldn't know how to implement that in code, I'm really new to python

Comment: What happens when you add `print(SA.count('\n'))` right under `SA = input('Copy paste essay: \n')`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225247/discussion-between-codeman-and-ann-zen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 3.x, you can use `sys.stdin.read()` to read multiline input on the console.

```
>>> import sys
>>> text = sys.stdin.read()
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
^Z
>>> print(text)
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>>>
```

To exit the input mode, you have to use `Ctrl`+`Z` which appears in the above shell snippet as `^Z`.

Comment: In the string (text) that you have included, do the enter keys count as '\n' chars?